# How can I make background video render in React's parent component?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, video

My video on the background is not playing. Instead it just renders a static image of the video.
Please refer to the return statement for the video tag.
I am certain that the folder path (../image/) is accurate.

I have tried many other guidelines on websites but they all simply render the image of the video, not play the video.

I have omitted most parts of the React functional component above because stackoverflow says this post has too much code. The components and such all work seamlessly.

```
import Video1 from '../image/Video1.mp4';


    return (



        <div id='container'>

            <video playsinline autoplay muted loop id="myVideo">
                <source src={Video1} type="video/mp4" />
            </video>


            <ExpansionView expansion={expansion} selectExpansion={setExpansion}/> 
            <p>current state of Naxxramas is {expansion['Naxxramas'].toString()}</p>
            

            <DisplayView data={allCards} expansion={expansion}/>
            {/* test */}
            
        </div>
    );
}
 
export default Container;
```

here is the css:

```
    #myVideo {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  object-fit: cover;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you used Create React App you could place your video files in the public folder.Create React App will copy the files to the final static page.If you don't use a Create React App setup you need to copy your video to the final bundle e.g. by using Webpack.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import ReactPlayer from 'react-player'

    class VideoRender extends Component {
        render () {
            return (
            <div className='video-wrapper'>
                <ReactPlayer
                className='react-player fixed-bottom'
                url= 'url for videos from public folder'
                width='100%'
                height='100%'
                controls = {true}
    
                />
            </div>
            )
        }
    }
    
    export default VideoRender;
```